# Saving two mutually referenced records in Rails 4.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Up until Rails 4.1 it was possible to start a transaction, create two records and reference them before committing changes into the DB.

Records are in the many-to-many relationship with existence constraint on both ends, i.e. there cannot be an empty group nor can a person not belong to at least one group.

Class outlines:

```
class Person
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  validates_presence_of :groups
end

class Group
  has_and_belongs_to_many :persons
  validates_presence_of :persons
end
```

Transaction code example:

```
Person.transaction do
  person = Person.new(...)
  group = Group.create!(..., persons: [person])
  person.groups << group
  person.save!
end
```

Is there a way to defer the existence check till the commit phase? Any better suggestion?

Comment: I think `inverse_of` is required

Comment: See my comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `inverse_of`. That should solve your problem:

```
class Person
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups, inverse_of: :groups
  ...
end

class Group
  has_and_belongs_to_many :persons, inverse_of: :persons
  ..
end
```

Comment: Hm, it's not documented for `has_and_belongs_to_many`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Hmm I see. Sorry about that. So why not use just has_many through?

Comment: The linking model (i.e. `PersonGroup` or something like that) is not needed and I was trying to avoid it.

The alternative solution would be to remove one `validates_presence_of` constraint and create that model's record first. Not very clean solution though...

Comment: Well my personal preference would be to use join model even if it would be just an empty model (I consider HABTM dangerous and not very flexible - what will you do if you will need to add some attributes on the relationship in the future?). But that's just my personal preference...